ECS connect container unhealthy during new deployments to ECS EC2
I have several ECS tasks running on EC2 using ECS service connect for internal communication. Sometimes, during new deployments, the ECS service connect container linked to these tasks becomes unhealthy, preventing the deployment from succeeding. This issue doesn't occur with every deployment.
These ECS tasks are GPU-based and take some time to start. I don't have any health check configured for the task definitions.
Capacity provider with auto scaling is configured to manage the EC2 instances.
